# Qual a diferença de . pra -> em PHP?

Tags: php

Qual a diferença entre eles? Peguei um exercício de "Relacionamento de Agregação" que tinha os 2, e não entendi o uso do . ao inves do ->

No caso, qual a diferença, por exemplo, disso:

```
$varTeste.abrirFuncao();
```

e disso:

```
$varTeste->abrirFuncao();
```

```
function lutar($l1, $l2){
        if($l1.getCategoria() == $l2.getCategoria()
                && ($l1 != $l2)){
                $this->aprovada = true;
                $this->desafiado = $l1;
                $this->desafiante = $l2;
        } else {

        }
    }
```

Fonte do exercício: https://youtu.be/lOOYBUQSRWU?t=8m1s

Comment: Tem certeza que o primeiro trecho é em PHP? No PHP o operator `.` faz concatenação, não para acessar métodos.

Comment: Não sabia que o `.` no PHP servia para chamar uma função, aqui da erro. Acho q ele não tem esta finalidade.

Comment: Tem como postar a fonte deste exercício?

Comment: Sim, tenho certeza. Fica dentro de uma class essa function com esse trecho. A fonte também vou por na edição.

Comment: Pronto, editei la.

Comment: @LucasCarvalho é erro de digitação eu acho.

Comment: Ele executa o código por volta dos [15 minutos](https://youtu.be/lOOYBUQSRWU?t=15m26s) e aparece o erro.

Comment: Não entendi o motivo do -1?

Comment: Entendi, eu não vi o vídeo todo gente, pôs é um curso, eu vou pausando e fazendo com ele. Tive uma dúvida, e vim perguntar. Obrigado Anderson, pelo comentário!

Comment: Rapaz, melhor assistir aula com outro professor :)

Comment: Não acho não Leo, eu aposto que o Guanabara é um dos melhores professores pra se aprender a programar no Brasil, por conta de sua didática.

Comment: É, pode ser, mas errar no básico é dose. Para mim, que não o conheço, foi um péssimo cartão de visitas.

Comment: @LucasCarvalho Pode ter certeza que não. É uma das pessoas que mais ensina coisas erradas. Ensina tudo torto, o LeoCaracciolo tem completa razão.

Comment: Não acho @LINQ gosto muito da didática dele. E do projeto Curso em Vídeo. Talvez pra vocês que sejam avançados, seja ruim, mas pra gente, que está aprendendo, um PROJETÃO que ele e A Hostnet fizeram, ajudaram MILHARES de pessoas. Eu, por exemplo, estou trabalhando por causa dele. Óbvio, que não é só ele, ja comprei livros, aqui mesmo no SOpt, entre outros lugares, mas o ponta pé inicial, que me fez apaixonar por programação, foi por causa dele.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Foi erro de digitação. Rode mais o vídeo e verá que quando ele roda o programa, aparece o erro.

https://youtu.be/lOOYBUQSRWU?t=15m26s

Para acessar um método no PHP é unicamente através do operador `->`, ou através do `::` para métodos estáticos. O operador `.` efetua a concatenação, então executar o código:

```
$l1.getCategoria() == $l2.getCategoria()
```

O PHP tentará concatenar a variável `$l1` com o retorno da função `getCategoria()` e tentar concatenar a variável `$l2` também com o retorno da função `getCategoria()`, verificando se os valores finais são iguais.

Tome muito cuidado que isso pode gerar um falso positivo. Por exemplo, vamos considerar dois objetos da classe `Foo`:

```
$l1 = new Foo("lutador 1");
$l2 = new Foo("lutador 2");

var_dump($l1.getCategoria() == $l2.getCategoria());
```

Vamos supor que a função `getCategoria` esteja definida no programa:

```
function getCategoria() {
    return "categoria";
}
```

Se a classe `Foo` possuir, por exemplo, o método `__toString`:

```
class Foo {

    public function __construct($name) {
        $this->name = $name;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return "classe Foo";
    }

}
```

Ao executar o código:

```
var_dump($l1.getCategoria() == $l2.getCategoria());
```

A saída será `bool(true)`, pois a comparação será `"classe Foocategoria" == "classe Foocategoria"`. Ou seja, ao invés de dar um erro, sua condição retornou verdadeira em um `if`. Isso pode gerar resultados inesperados na aplicação e será bem difícil de encontrar a fonte do erro, pois sendo uma sintaxe válida, qualquer interpretador aceitará o código e não te mostrará nem um aviso.

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/Phclpk).

Imagina se você faz a condição abaixo:

```
if ($l1.getCategoria() == $l2.getCategoria()) {
    mysqli_query($conn, "DROP DATABASE sopt");
}
```

O estrago que daria por causa de um operador errado...

Comment: Obrigado Anderson!

Answer (score 4):

O ponto `(.)` no `PHP` é usado para realizar concateção de `strings` como no exemplo abaixo:

```
$nome = 'Meu nome';
$sobreNome = 'Meu sobrenome';
echo $nome.$sobreNome
// Saida: Meu NomeMeu sobrenome
// Note que não existem espaços entre os nome pois não são usados espaços nas strings.
```

A seta `(->)` é utilizado para chamar funções de classes, enquanto outras linguagens utilizam o `ponto` para chamar função o `PHP` utiliza essas "setinhas", veja o exemplo:

```
// Java, Ruby, Javascript e etc...
classe.funcao();

// PHP
classe->funcao();
```

Comment: Não foi o caso, foi erro de digitação do professor, mas obrigado pela informação!